# How to turn off Firefox forms autocomplete for only certain websites, or for all sites temporarily?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, autocomplete

I want to turn off Firefox autocomplete, but only for specific websites--not for the entire interwebs. My language course has an online workbook, and the autocomplete keeps giving me the answers if I need to re-do an exercise. The tutorials I've found online all tell me to clear out my form history. I don't want to do this. I just want autocomplete to not work for a specific set of websites, or alternately turn it off temporarily. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm curious as to why auto-complete is causing a problem or annoyance, as there may be better solutions or paradigm shifts that would address it.

Answer (score 2):

The [Form History Control extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/af/firefox/addon/form-history-control/) for Firefox allows you to clear the AutoComplete storage for specific websites, and supports many other advanced AutoComplete tasks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to [my JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/rujTq/).
2. In the bottom right corner there is a link with the text ACOff.
3. Drag this link to your bookmark toolbar.

Now go to your website - click the link, and all fields with `type=text` have their autocomplete turned off.

Comment: Code looks good but it didn't work for http://rhymezone.com. Firefox 33.3.1 on OSX 10.10.1.